# Horizontal scroll, Load content via AJAX

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this scroll event and I want to load new content via ajax before the scrollbar reaches end. So for example 40px before scrollbar reaches end I want to load new content.

This works but it loads content many times. Many ajax request are fired during scroll. I want to load new content only when scrollbar gets near end but my functions loads content during the whole scroll event.

```
//load with ajax
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {

    var el = event.target;

    if((el.scrollWidth - el.scrollLeft) < (el.offsetWidth + 40)) {
        //get
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: you can do this by adding a flag so it's only triggered once. I had the same problem before and found that another way i found was to always watch the position of the last div relative to screen and scroll and use that to trigger the lazyloading. Can't remember why but I found this to be more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a quick fiddle in jQuery - just to illustrate the tracking the last div with `.getBoundingClientRect().left;`, if you don't want to do this then it illustrates the `loading` variable which prevents the conditional statement from firing again whilst it's true.

```js
var n = 0, loading = false, lastDiv;

function addboxes(){
  for( i=0; i < 6; i++){
   $('body').append('<div class="box" style="left:'+(n+i*250)+'px;"></div>');
  }
 n+=6*250;
  loading = false;
}

addboxes();
// just to set up sideways boxes

$(document).on('scroll',function(e){
 var lastDiv = $('.box').last(); // get the last div
 var lastLeft = lastDiv[0].getBoundingClientRect().left; // get distance between lastDiv's left edge and windows left edge
  var windowWidth = $(window).width(); // get window width
  
 $("#monitor").text(" lastLeft ="+lastLeft+", windowWidth ="+windowWidth);

 if( lastLeft < windowWidth && !loading ){ // last box is now just appearing!
   loading = true; // flag to prevent multiple firings
  addboxes(); // add more boxes!
    $(window).trigger('resize'); // just incase window doesn't recalc for new content, probably not necessary
  }

});
```

```css
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}

#monitor{
  position: fixed;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 30px;
  color: #09f;
  z-index: 333;
}
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="monitor">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @sam0 can u guide in this question ?????http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713529/horizontal-scrollbar-does-not-work-but-works-in-vertical-scroll