# horizontal scroll works in vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var ID=$(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");var oldID=0;var loadContent=false;var loadedID=[];$(document).ready(function(){function loadlovephoto(){if(loadContent==true){ID=$(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");REFER=$(".referid:last").attr("id");$('div#lastlove_loader').html('<img src="/files/loading.gif">');var pathname=window.location.pathname;if(pathname=="/jquery"){$.post("jquery/morethread123?action=get&lastlove_id="+ID,function(data){if(data!=""){$(".game-lg-2:last").after(data);loadContent=false;}
$('div#lastlove_loader').empty();});}else{$.post("/touch/w2et/moregames.php?action=get&lastlove_id="+ ID,function(data){if(data!=""){$(".game-lg-2:last").after(data);loadContent=false;}
$('div#lastlove_loader').empty();});}oldID=$(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");}};if(loadContent==false){$(window).scroll(function(){ID=$(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");if(($(window).scrollLeft()>=$(document).width()-$(window).width()-300)&&ID!=oldID){if(ID>1){loadContent=true;loadlovephoto();}}});}});
```

```css
html,body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
 } 

.row-horizon {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.row-horizon > [class*="col-lg"], .row-horizon > [class*="col-md"], .row-horizon > [class*="col-sm"], .row-horizon > [class*="col-xs"],.row-horizon > [class*="game-lg"], .row-horizon > [class*="game-md"], .row-horizon > [class*="game-sm"], .row-horizon > [class*="game-xs"] {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

   
@media (min-width: 1200px) 

  .row-horizon > .col-lg-2 {
    width: 15%;
  }
 
}




  
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row-horizon > .game-md-12 {
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .row-horizon > .game-md-1 {
    width: 7.5%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-2 {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-1 {
    width: 7.5%;
  }
}


#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 overflow:hidden;height:0px;

}
#style-11:hover::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 overflow-y:scroll;height:4px;background-color:#F5F5F5;
}
#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: #3366FF;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,
                                           rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%,
             transparent 25%,
             transparent 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%,
             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 75%,
             transparent 75%,
             transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 12
 */


 .sliding {
 overflow-x:auto;
     overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
 margin-left:2%;
 } 
 
 

.btn-circle.btn-xxl {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 45px 3px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 65px;
}
  
 .post a.title {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    color: #215399;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Way2enjoy -Innovate it</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/js/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/js/moregames.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(function() {

   $("#main-content > .row").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
    
      event.preventDefault();

   });

});



</script>




<div class="container testimonial-group" id="main-content">
  <div class="row row-horizon" id="style-13">
<h5>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Facebook Games/Quiz</h5>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="99"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/99"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/your-profile-picture.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/99">let us guess your age based on your profile picture?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/99'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="100"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/100"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/want-to-kiss-you.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/100">how many people want to kiss you?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/100'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="101"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/101"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/liked-photo-on-facebook.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/101">which is your most liked photo on facebook?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/101'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="102"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/102"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/want-a-baby.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/102">how many people want to have a baby with you?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/102'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="103"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/2/103"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/who-loves-you-lot.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/2/103">who loves you but nobody knows?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/2/103'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="104"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/104"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/hurts-you.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/104">what hurts you the most?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/104'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="105"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/105"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/remember-about-you.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/105">what will people remember about you?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/105'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div>
<div class="game-lg-2 game-md-3 game-sm-4 game-xs-6 game-xsx-12" id="106"><div class="post">
<div class="img img-wrap"><a href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/106"><img src="http://way2enjoy.com/thumb/facebook-fun/were-born.jpg"></a></div><div class="txt"><a class="title" href="/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/106">what did god say when you were born?</a><p class="desc"></p></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div></div><div class="fb_share" onclick="location.href='/pdf/4/fbb/process.php/1/106'" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0"><i class="fb_f"></i><span>View Your Results</span></div><br></div> <div class="loadmore" id="lastlove_loader"></div>
</div>

        

  <hr>

      <div class="row row-horizon" id="style-11">
    <h5 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Fun</h5>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/gifs" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xxl">GIFs</a>
            </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/jokes" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xxl">Jokes</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/wishes" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xxl">Wishes</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/share" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xxl">Text 2 Pic</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/birthday" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xxl">Birthday</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/a" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-xxl">Celebrity</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/photos-desigirls.php" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xxl">Girls</a>
            </div>
             
                 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/hollywood-celebrity" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xxl">Hollywood</a>
            </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/good-night" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xxl">Good<br/>Night</a>
            </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
<a href="http://way2enjoy.com/good-morning" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-xxl">Good<br/>Morning</a> 
            </div>
            
  </div>
  <hr>
 <div class="row row-horizon" id="style-11">
    <h5 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;PDF/Image/MP3 Online Tools</h5>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/word-to-pdf-online-free-without-email" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xxl">PDF Tools</a>
            </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/compress-png" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xxl">PNG/JPG<br/>Compress</a>
  </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">

           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/resize-image" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xxl">Resize<br/>Image</a>
           
            </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/mp3-cutter" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xxl">MP3 Tools</a>
            </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/word-to-pdf-online-free-without-email" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xxl">Word to PDF</a>
           
            </div>
              
  </div>
  <hr>


 <div class="row row-horizon" id="style-11">
    <h5 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Health</h5>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/diet-chart-loose-gain-weight" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xxl">Diet Plan<br />Maker</a>
            </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/benefits" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xxl">Fruit<br />Benefits</a>
            </div>
           
  </div>
  <hr>
 <div class="row row-horizon" id="style-11">
   <h5 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mobile</h5>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/mobile-under-10000" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xxl">Mobile below<br />10000</a>
            </div>
           <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/mobile-under-15000" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-xxl">Mobile below<br />15000</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/mobile-under-5000" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xxl">Mobile below<br />5000</a>
            </div>
          
  </div>
  <hr>
 <div class="row row-horizon" id="style-11">
   <h5 >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Shop</h5>
         <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-xsx-12">
           <a href="http://way2enjoy.com/medicines" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-xxl">Itching<br />Solution</a>
            </div>
       
          
  </div>
  <hr>


</div>



  
</body>
</html>
```

i have created horizontal scroll for my page and it does not work as expected.when we scroll horizontally it does not work but when we scroll vertically it loads contents in horizontal tab.
i tried several thread which suggested the use of overflow-hidden but that did not helped.

[here](http://way2enjoy.com/ads/1/frontpagenew1.php) is the demo link

here is my js code

```
var ID = $(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");
var oldID = 0;
var loadContent = false;
var loadedID = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    function loadlovephoto() {
        if (loadContent == true) {
            ID = $(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");
            REFER = $(".referid:last").attr("id");
            $('div#lastlove_loader').html('<img src="/files/loading.gif">');
            var pathname = window.location.pathname;
            if (pathname == "/jquery") {
                $.post("jquery/morethread123?action=get&lastlove_id=" + ID, function(data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                        $(".game-lg-2:last").after(data);
                        loadContent = false;
                    }
                    $('div#lastlove_loader').empty();
                });
            } else {
                $.post("/touch/w2et/moregames.php?action=get&lastlove_id=" + ID, function(data) {
                    if (data != "") {
                        $(".game-lg-2:last").after(data);
                        loadContent = false;
                    }
                    $('div#lastlove_loader').empty();
                });
            }
            oldID = $(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");
        }
    };
    if (loadContent == false) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            ID = $(".game-lg-2:last").attr("id");
            if (($(window).scrollLeft() >= $(document).width() - $(window).width() - 300) && ID != oldID) {
                if (ID > 1) {
                    loadContent = true;
                    loadlovephoto();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

here is css

```
html,body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
 } 

.row-horizon {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.row-horizon > [class*="col-lg"], .row-horizon > [class*="col-md"], .row-horizon > [class*="col-sm"], .row-horizon > [class*="col-xs"],.row-horizon > [class*="game-lg"], .row-horizon > [class*="game-md"], .row-horizon > [class*="game-sm"], .row-horizon > [class*="game-xs"] {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.row-horizon > .col-xsm-12 {
  width: 90%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-11 {
  width: 82.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-10 {
  width: 75%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-9 {
  width: 67.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-8 {
  width: 60%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-7 {
  width: 52.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-6 {
  width: 45%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-5 {
  width: 37.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-4 {
  width: 30%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-3 {
  width: 22.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-2 {
  width: 15%;
}
.row-horizon > .col-xsm-1 {
  width: 7.5%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-12 {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-11 {
    width: 82.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-10 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-9 {
    width: 67.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-8 {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-7 {
    width: 52.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-6 {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-5 {
    width: 37.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-4 {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-3 {
    width: 22.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-2 {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .col-lg-1 {
    width: 7.5%;
  }
}




.row-horizon > .game-xsm-12 {
  width: 90%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-11 {
  width: 82.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-10 {
  width: 75%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-9 {
  width: 67.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-8 {
  width: 60%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-7 {
  width: 52.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-6 {
  width: 45%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-5 {
  width: 37.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-4 {
  width: 30%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-3 {
  width: 22.5%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-2 {
  width: 15%;
}
.row-horizon > .game-xsm-1 {
  width: 7.5%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-12 {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-11 {
    width: 82.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-10 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-9 {
    width: 67.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-8 {
    width: 60%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-7 {
    width: 52.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-6 {
    width: 45%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-5 {
    width: 37.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-4 {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-3 {
    width: 22.5%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-2 {
    width: 15%;
  }
  .row-horizon > .game-lg-1 {
    width: 7.5%;
  }
}



#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    overflow:hidden;height:0px;

}
#style-16:hover::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 overflow-y:scroll;height:4px;background-color:#F5F5F5;
}

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,
                                              #e4f5fc 0%,
                                              #bfe8f9 50%,
                                              #9fd8ef 51%,
                                              #2ab0ed 100%);
}

.btn-circle.btn-xxl {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  padding: 45px 3px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 65px;
}
here is demo link http://way2enjoy.com/ads/1/frontpagenew1.php
```

issue in first row. when we scroll horizontally it should load more games but it loads more games when we scroll vertically
 i have inserted raw html as moregames are loaded dynamically i cant add php code in snipset as it will not connect to remote database

Comment: Please add a code snippet to your question or a link to a service like JSFiddle, so that we can easily look and reproduce your problem.

Comment: can you clarify a little how you need it to behave? horizontal scroll on horizontal elements only and vertical on window only? note that the scrollbar on your horizontal elements can't be dragged, so if you disable vertical on these I'm not sure how they'll move - unless you use something like nicescroll.js

Comment: @nicescoll is not working in mobile. its known issue. when i move for my game category (first row) it should load next games as users scroll horizontally . when mouse/cursor is not there in first row and users uses mouse wheel or scroll then it should scroll vertically. everything works as expected only problem in first row which loads more content only when we scroll vertically